# Insert into table with one column value as select query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

My code is something like this

```
insert into table (A,B,C,D) values
('abb','select appCode,pkid from table where party_id='||party_id,sysdate,user);
```

The `party_id` here is varchar and it comes as IN clause in Stored proc, So if partyid comes as 123 in stored procedure
Then I want to see the values in database as
select appCode, pkid from table where party_id='123'

but thats not happening instead it goes as
select appCode, pkid from table where party_id=123

sugestions please.

Comment: Firstly, you have 5 values being inserted in a table of 4 columns!

Comment: So you're trying to put an SQL SELECT (as a string) into column `B` and you need to know how to quote `party_id`? Which database?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK: Count again please, there are four values in the VALUES, not five.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: mu is too short....Yes thats right..Thats what i want...Its Oracle.I am using Stored Proc to do this

Comment: It seems a bit strange to be inserting a SQL statement into a table. What is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
insert into table (A,B,C,D) values
('abb'
,'select appCode,pkid from table where party_id=''' || party_id || ''''
,sysdate
,user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
(
    t1   VARCHAR2 (100),
    t2   VARCHAR2 (100),
    d1   DATE,
    t3   VARCHAR2 (100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (param user_objects.object_type%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO  tab1 (t1,t2,d1,t3) values
          ('abc','SELECT object_id  
            FROM     user_objects
          WHERE     object_type = '''||param||'''',SYSDATE,'scott');
END;
```

and execute procedure

```
EXEC test_proc('TABLE')
```